# Don't create any resources if a resource name is taken

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

We have a bicep file with a dozen related resources and a resource name prefix as a parameter (with the postfixes hardcoded).

Is there a *bicep/ARM* way to first check if any of the resulting (prefix+postfix) resource names are taken before creating *any* of the resources?

I tried `--what-if` and it doesn't detect if a resource name is taken.

I know about the `uniqueString` function. We could also introduce a parameter for each resource name with a default and run the bicep file again with a different resource name for the offending resource.

A non-bicep way of checking would be to use the REST API / CLI to check a resource name is taken.

Comment: You could use what-if operation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/deploy-what-if?tabs=azure-powershell%2CCLI

Comment: @Thomas, I tried and unfortunately it doesn't detect if a resource name is taken.

Comment: sorry to hear that, then not sure tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bicep don't have any ways to check resource name availability. Bicep only used to interact with Resource manager controller and pass the resource declaration to create resource.

If you want to check if the resource exists or not for any particular resource provider the best way is to use REST API which internally used by ARM also.

REST API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/check-existence?view=rest-resources-2021-04-01

The REST API Varies based on type of resource providers.
Example REST API for Api Management validating the resource name availability:

POST [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/*Microsoft.ApiManagement*/checkNameAvailability?api-version=2022-08-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/providers/*Microsoft.ApiManagement*/checkNameAvailability?api-version=2022-08-01)

Example REST API for ServiceBus validating the resource name availability:
GET [https://management.core.windows.net/{subscription](https://management.core.windows.net/%7Bsubscription) ID}/services/ServiceBus/CheckNamespaceAvailability/?namespace=

**How to check whether a resource exists**

HEAD [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourcegroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/{resourceProviderNamespace}/{parentResourcePath}/{resourceType}/{resourceName}?api-version=2021-04-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourcegroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/%7BresourceProviderNamespace%7D/%7BparentResourcePath%7D/%7BresourceType%7D/%7BresourceName%7D?api-version=2021-04-01)

**Reference**:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/check-existence?view=rest-resources-2021-04-01

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `WhatIf` in deployment script and `existing` in Bicep?

1. `WhatIf` help to check if resource deployed or not.
2. `existing` help to reduce bicep modifications.

`sample.ps1`

```
$resoucreGroupName = "test-vm-rg"

$param = @{
    vnetName = "wbtestvnet1"
    location = "eastus"
    newOrExisting = "new"
}

$deploymentName = "testvnetdeployment"

$templateFile = ".\sample.bicep"

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name $deploymentName -ResourceGroupName $resoucreGroupName -TemplateFile $templateFile `
-TemplateParameterObject $param -WhatIf
```

`sample.bicep`

```
param vnetName string
param vnetPrefix string = '10.0.0.0/16'
param vmSubnetPrefix string = '10.0.0.0/24'
@description('location for all resources.')
param location string
@allowed([
  'new'
  'existing'
])
param newOrExisting string

resource vnet 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-11-01' = if (newOrExisting == 'new') {
  name: vnetName
  location: location
  properties: {
    addressSpace: {
      addressPrefixes: [
        vnetPrefix
      ]
    }
    subnets: [
      {
        name: 'vmSubnet1'
        properties: {
          addressPrefix: vmSubnetPrefix
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
resource vnetExisting 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2022-11-01' existing = if (newOrExisting == 'existing') {
  name: vnetName
}

output vnetId string = ((newOrExisting == 'new') ? vnet.id : vnetExisting.id)
```

Comment: I did try what-if and it doesn't detect when a resource name is taken. Existing is useful but not related.

Comment: I don't know why you think "what-if" doesn't detect resource name is token, when the same name resouce deployed, it will out the NoChange, if not deployed, it will show Create, the sample above "Existing" here is to reduce bicep modification but not to check resource existing, I already mentioned. If you do not want to use the pattern of "what-if", the only way is to check "resouce name token" is to use API/CLI/SDK checking before-hand, there is no better way here.

Comment: By "taken" I mean available for use, it could be taken by anyone else if it's globally unique.

Comment: ok, sorry, I misunderstander it.